# Socket.io websocket connection works in localhost but not in aws server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, websocket, socket.io

When initializing the socket connection (wss) using sockets.io in localhost the connection gets established properly. But when intiailzing the connection to the aws server following error message is show.

```
websocket.js:83 WebSocket connection to
 'wss://domainName.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket&sid=' failed:
```

The only thing that changes when the code is run on aws is that on the client side the parameter passed to the io is the domain name of the website. Only the domain name is given without a port number

**Client Side code**

```
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';

let socket = null;
export function initialize() {
    if (socket == null) {
        socket = io('https://domainName.com/');
    }
    return socket;
}
```

**Server Side Code**

```
var io = require('socket.io')(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: '*',
    },
});

io.on('connection', (client) => {
    client.on('subscribe', (room) => {
        client.join(room);
    });

    client.on('unsubscribe', (room) => {
        client.leave(room);
    });

});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue :(